# Difference between Sprintf and printf in Perl

Tags: perl, printf

What is the difference between `sprintf` and `printf` in Perl?

I'm really confused with those functions.

I know about `printf`. It is used for `STDOUT`, but I want know in depth of these functions.

Comment: refer this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=20519

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sprintf` just returns a formatted string, `printf` prints it to a filehandle.

```
printf HANDLE "%s", $arg
```

can (very redundantly) be written as

```
$formatted = sprintf "%s", $arg
print HANDLE $formatted
```

Of course, this specific example is most naturally written as

```
print HANDLE $arg
```

because the format string I used for an example is so trivial as to be useless.

Of course, HANDLE is optional, and defaults to STDOUT, although you can also change the default with `select`.

Comment: format string means http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-sprintf.html with this symbols?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good link. `sprintf "%-23s\n", $arg` already does something interesting and useful.

Comment: `print HANDLE $formatted` is different in that print adds $\ to the output, but printf does not.

Comment: in your example doesn't have any difference between `sprintf` and `printf`.i need difference between both of them.can you show me this difference  in one simple example.?

Comment: @user3114045 :  tripleee shows the difference: `sprintf` returns a string (it doesn't write anything to any file handle anywhere) while `printf` formats a string **and** sends it to a file handle (STDOUT by default, although you can specify another).

Comment: perl -l sets $\, but it works even without: `perl -we'$\="def\n"; print "abc"'`